Issues with Generic Type Inference in atomFamily causing duplicate Atom Key errors in Recoil
I’m trying to use Recoil's atomFamily with TypeScript generics to get precise type inference. However, I’m encountering errors related to duplicate atom keys. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
I initially defined my atomFamily like this:
export const fieldUpdatedValueState = atomFamily<unknown, { fieldId: string; formId: string }>({
  key: 'fieldUpdatedValueState',
  default: undefined,
  effects: ({ formId, fieldId }) => [
    ({ onSet }) => {
      onSet((newData, _, isReset) => {
        if (isReset || spec(isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty).test(newData)) {
          actionsResolver.resetChange(formId, fieldId);
        } else {
          actionsResolver.addChange(formId, fieldId);
        }
      });
    },
  ],
});

I then modified it to use a generic type:
export const fieldUpdatedValueState = <T extends FieldIds>() =>
  atomFamily<Fields[T], { fieldId: T; formId: string }>({
    key: 'fieldUpdatedValueState',
    default: undefined,
    effects: ({ formId, fieldId }) => [
      ({ onSet }) => {
        onSet((newData, _, isReset) => {
          if (isReset || spec(isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty).test(newData)) {
            actionsResolver.resetChange(formId, fieldId);
          } else {
            actionsResolver.addChange(formId, fieldId);
          }
        });
      },
    ],
  });

I use a custom hook to interact with this atom family:
export function useSetField<T extends keyof Fields>(formId: string, fieldId: T) {
  const fieldUpdatedValue = fieldUpdatedValueState<T>();

  return useSetRecoilState(fieldUpdatedValue({ formId, fieldId }));
}

After refactoring to use the generic type, I’m seeing multiple console errors like:
Expectation Violation: Duplicate atom key "fieldUpdatedValueState__{"fieldId":"station_id[]","formId":"list"}".
Expectation Violation: Duplicate atom key "fieldUpdatedValueState__{"fieldId":"search","formId":"list"}".
Expectation Violation: Duplicate atom key "fieldUpdatedValueState__{"fieldId":"status[]","formId":"list"}".

What could be causing these duplicate atom key errors? It seems like using a function to create the atomFamily is leading to these issues. How can I properly use generics with atomFamily without running into duplicate key problems?

Define atomFamily outside of components to avoid creating multiple instances with duplicate keys. Use the generic types directly inside your hook or component. This approach ensures unique atom keys and prevents duplicate key errors.

My atomFamily is not defined inside of my components. It is located in its own .ts file. I'm already using my generic types directly inside my hook and component but I also need to pass it to my atomFamily so that the types are properly inferred.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
